# ASP.NET MVC5 Bundles How to fall back to my hosted library if Google jqueryUI fails using bundles?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am creating an asp.net mvc app. I have created bundles for my scripts and stylesheets and I have used google cdn for each of the bundles.
I have two questions:
1. How and where do I create a fall back in case google's jquery and jqueryUI cdn fails?
2. Do I have to create a fall back for each bundle(i.e for the stylebundles as well)?

This is my bundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js").Include(
"~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));


        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval", "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.17.0/jquery.validate.min.js").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at https://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css", "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/themes/base/css", "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css").Include(
 "~/Content/themes/base/core.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/resizable.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/selectable.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/accordion.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/autocomplete.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/button.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/dialog.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/slider.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/tabs.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/datepicker.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/progressbar.css",
 "~/Content/themes/base/theme.css"));



        BundleTable.EnableOptimizations = true;
        bundles.UseCdn = true;
    }
```

This is my layout.cshtml

```
 <head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title> 
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
@Styles.Render("~/Content/themes/base/css")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
```

```
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, it does not make a lot of sense to put the CDNs in a bundle, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17439805/when-not-to-use-mvc-bundling/17447852#17447852). Just make sure you are using a minified version.

See the example below, for adding the fallbacks:

Put bootstrap CSS and Modernizr in the `<head>` of your HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    /* Referencing bootstrap CSS from CDN */
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">

    /* Referencing Modernizr from CDN */
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.3/modernizr.js"></script>
```

And add these JS references at the bottom of your `<body>`:

```
<body>
    .
    .
    .

    /* Modernizer fallback */
    <script>if (typeof Modernizr === 'undefined') { document.write('<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.min.js"><\/script>'); }</script>

    /* jQuery CDN and fallback */
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>');</script>

    /* jQuery UI CDN and fallback */
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js" integrity="sha256-VazP97ZCwtekAsvgPBSUwPFKdrwD3unUfSGVYrahUqU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>if (typeof jQuery.ui === 'undefined') { document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"><\/script>'); }</script>

    /* popper CDN and fallback, this is only needed for bootstrap 4, remove for bootstrap 3 */
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>if (typeof (Popper) === 'undefined') { document.write('<script src="/Script/umd/popper.min.js"><\/script>') }</script>

    /* bootstrap CDN and fallback */
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-ChfqqxuZUCnJSK3+MXmPNIyE6ZbWh2IMqE241rYiqJxyMiZ6OW/JmZQ5stwEULTy" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script>window.jQuery.fn.modal || document.write('<script src="/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"><\/script>')</script>

    /* fallback for bootstrap stylesheet */
    <script>(function ($) { $(function () { if ($('body').css('color') !== 'rgb(33, 37, 41)') { $('head').prepend('<link rel="stylesheet" href="/Content/bootstrap.min.css">'); } }); })(window.jQuery);</script>

    /* jQuery Validate CDN and fallback */
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
    <script>if (typeof $().validate === 'undefined') { document.write('<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"><\/script>'); }</script>
</body>
```

---

I also recommend getting your bootstrap CDN from [Bootstrap 3 official page](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/), because these CDNs have `integrity` and `crossorigin` attributes, which validate the the reliability of the CDN files... (and the same for your jQuery and jQuery.ui), [see this for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32039568/what-are-the-integrity-and-crossorigin-attributes).

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

---

### Update

If you want to put the CDN in a bundle (not sure why?) this is how to do, from [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/performance/bundling-and-minification#using-a-cdn):

> //add link to jquery on the CDN
>
> ```
> var jqueryCdnPath = "https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js";
>
> bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery",
>             jqueryCdnPath).Include(
>             "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
> ```

And this is how you add it to your page:

> ```
> @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
>
>         <script type="text/javascript">
>             if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {
>                 var e = document.createElement('script');
>                 e.src = '@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js")';
>                 e.type = 'text/javascript';
>                 document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(e);
>
>             }
>         </script>
> ```

Comment: Thank you! Just wondering how the cdn are linked to each bundle as a fallback, is document.write only linking to one script?

Comment: My question is how to use bundling and cdn?

Comment: how to create a fall back for cdn when i publish my app?

Comment: @JaneCohen: I have updated my answer to show how to use CDNs in a bundle

Comment: I understand your point about not using bundles.. just wondering what I would   do in the layout for the style bundles(that have more than one stylesheet), if i am not using bundling, how would i attach a cdn fall back method for each style

Comment: please see the example above. Put all your CSS and JS files in a bundle, except for those being referenced from CDN.

Comment: My question is how to attach a cdn with a fallback  to the minified version of jquery.ui  css and bootstrap css(where in your example have you shown this? Thank you!

Comment: My example does not contain fallback for jQuery ui css. But there is a fallback for bootstrap css (which is very clear, because I have commented the code)... I think you are too attached to the term bundle... bundle is just packaging of files together... there are no bundles in my example, just .js or .css files.

Comment: Sorry, thanks for your patience! Im not so clear with your bootstrap.css example, are you referencing the entire bootstrap.css ot only part of it? Can you show me an example of a fallback using jquery ui.css ?